# C# LINQ to SQL - how to Replace inside "..."?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have rows in CSV like this:
**"04/26/2006,AAA,BBB,\"CCC,DDD , EE,TT\",21.32"**

How I can replace all commas inside this row ?

**\"CCC,DDD , EE,TT\"**
just if Row is between two signs: **\"...\"**

Because if I do this:

```
var DBData = from line in lines.Skip(1)
                                 let data = line.Split(new Char[] { ',' })
                                 select new DB_Table
                                 {
                                 ...
                                 };
```

I have spitted Row:

**04/26/2006

AAA

BBB

CCC

DDD

EE

TT

...**

But i need like this:

**04/26/2006

AAA

BBB

CCC DDD EE TT

...**

Comment: Do you really need to parse it manually? There are quite a few parsers available already on nuget, such as https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a CSV parsing library as well, but you can use a Regular Expression as a work around:

```
var p = new Regex(@"(?<=""[^""]*),(?=[^""]*"")", RegexOptions.Compiled);

var DBData = from line in lines.Skip(1)
             let data = p.Replace(line, " ").Split(new Char[] { ',' })
             select new DB_Table {
                 ...
             };
```

Comment: Great, thanks !!! It is really works !!! I spent a lot of time on this - you saved me :)